# Xampp setup doesnt start when executing the code

Tags: xampp

When executing

```
chmod +x xampp-linux-x64-7.0.26-0-installer.run
./xampp-linux-x64-7.0.26-0-installer.run
```

xampp setup does not start, it runs on terminal like in the Screenshot
[image]

Comment: that is the expected behaviour, xampp gets installed. Do you expect to see a GUI ?

Comment: yes of course , thats what the tutorial  the  said. https://askubuntu.com/questions/904599/install-xampp-on-ubuntu-16-04                   i followed the tutorial.any updates about the tutorial or a tutorial about installing on ubuntu 17.10 will be great.

Comment: I don't see any information in your link, that a GUI should come up.