# Connecting MySQL to c++ Ubuntu

Tags: mysql, c++

I want to access my database using MySQL in c++ programs.
I know that I can connect MySQL with c++ code blocks with using `xampp` server and `Dev-C++` in windows but in case of Ubuntu, I don't have any idea.

How can I connect c++ with MySQL in Ubuntu?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL Connector/C++ (*libmysqlcppconn-dev*) is a MySQL database connector for C++. To install it open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt install libmysqlcppconn-dev
```

This package contains the development files (headers, static library).

For a server you can use Apache (*apache2*) or [XAMPP](https://askubuntu.com/questions/904599/) as in Windows.