# Cannot install XAMPP on my Chromebook

Tags: xampp

I am having a problem with my Acer Chromebook 314. I am trying to install XAMPP for Linux, but it does not work. I tried downloading this by running the command:

```
sudo apt-get install xampp
```

and got an error message:

```
Unable to locate package `xampp`
```

Can someone help me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you run: `sudo apt-get update` before? Also, I'll like to tell you that there's no package known as `"xampp"`. Which OS (Système d'exploitation) are you using?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Install xampp on ubuntu 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/904599/install-xampp-on-ubuntu-16-04)

Answer (score 1):

There is no package named `xampp` in the Ubuntu repositories, which is why apt cannot locate it.

To install the XAMPP stack, go to http://apachefriends.org/index.html and follow the install instructions there.